# MySQL is null doesn't return anything

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select 
    emp.name, emp.birthdate, emp.ssn, emp.current_employee, 
    german.introduction as "German Intro", german.work_experience as "German Work Experience", german.education as "German Education",
    chinese.introduction as "Chinese Intro", chinese.work_experience as "Chinese Work Experience", chinese.education as "Chinese Education"
from employees emp
left join contact_info german on emp.id = german.id_employee
left join contact_info chinese on emp.id = chinese.id_employee
where emp.name like '%peter%' 
and (german.id_language = 1 or german.id_language IS NULL)
and (chinese.id_language = 2 or chinese.id_language IS NULL)
```

The create queries for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_info` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_employee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_language` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `introduction` text,
  `work_experience` text,
  `education` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `current_employee` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I do have a record for Peter in the employee log. And I have a row in the contact_info table with German texts, but I don't have a row in the contact_info table with Chinese texts

I expected to get all the info about Peter with the German texts filled and the Chinese ones as NULL, but I end getting no results. Any idea what I am missing?

Extra info: the language table consists of 3 languages: German, Chinese and English and in future there might be more languages to be added. if this query somehow could be set up that it automatically loads all languages at once that would be super awesome

Comment: if you remove `emp.name like '%peter%' `  or  `(chinese.id_language = 2 or chinese.id_language IS NULL)`, do you get different results?

Comment: It seems to work. Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b7128/1), unless your tables contain different data then mine.

Comment: yes, if I remove the `emp.name like '%peter%' ` I get all the rows that have no language information at all

Comment: @Icemanind thanks for the fiddle but indeed in your fiddle it was missing content for the contact_info table, which I did have (only for German, not for Chinese). Got it fixed now due to answer below, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do like this and add `id_language` to your join criteria.

```
select 
    emp.name, emp.birthdate, emp.ssn, emp.current_employee, 
    german.introduction as "German Intro", german.work_experience as "German Work Experience", german.education as "German Education",
    chinese.introduction as "Chinese Intro", chinese.work_experience as "Chinese Work Experience", chinese.education as "Chinese Education"
from employees emp
left join contact_info german on emp.id = german.id_employee AND german.id_language = 1
left join contact_info chinese on emp.id = chinese.id_employee AND chinese.id_language = 2
where emp.name like '%peter%' 
and (german.id_language = 1 or german.id_language IS NULL)
and (chinese.id_language = 2 or chinese.id_language IS NULL)
```

Comment: Quote: 'I think' - I'm absolutely sure, was about to type this same answer. In this case you could remove the where-exrpession about this parts. Explanation: without this expression in the `ON`-part the `LEFT JOIN` would succeed, because there is a `contact_info chinese` with `emp.id = chinese.id_employee`. However that join results in the germam language being joined so `chinese_language` would be neither `2` nor `NULL`

Comment: thank you so much, and also @petervanderwal for explaining why it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `left join` the conditions should (normally) go in the `on` not the `where`.  So:

```
select emp.name, emp.birthdate, emp.ssn, emp.current_employee, 
       german.introduction as "German Intro", german.work_experience as "German Work Experience", german.education as "German Education",
       chinese.introduction as "Chinese Intro", chinese.work_experience as "Chinese Work Experience", chinese.education as "Chinese Education"
from employees emp left join
     contact_info german 
     on emp.id = german.id_employee and german.id_language = 1 left join 
     contact_info chinese
     on emp.id = chinese.id_employee and chinese.id_language = 2
where emp.name like '%peter%' ;
```

Including the conditions in the `where` is redundant.